# Правильный зум картинки

Tags: изображения, javascript, алгоритм

Добрый день!

Необходимо сделать приближение картинки на JS. Сам зум я реализовал через увеличеие размеров изображение, но я никак не могу придумать как центрировать увеличенную картинку.

Может быть кто-нибудь знает алгоритм центирования картинки? В идеале сделать так что бы при зуме картинка сдвигала центр в ту точку, где находится указатель мыши.

Comment: Покажите на jsfiddle, как именно сделан зум.

Тоже нужно что-то вроде http://rvolve.com/zoom_pic.php?

PS что среди тегов делает "c++"?

Comment: Сам зум сделать получилось, но теперь появилась проблема с очисткой canvas.

Вот код:
http://jsfiddle.net/L2648/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сам когда то сталкивался с подобной задачей, тоже создавал темы на форумах

[Алгоритм для масштабирования изображения](http://www.cyberforum.ru/javascript/thread639859.html)
и вот

[как сделать img zoom](http://javascript.ru/forum/events/30784-kak-sdelat-img-zoom.html)

там я думаю хватит инфы.

Comment: К сожалению не нашел ответа среди ссылок. Может быть я плохо искал, но там было решение только для центрирования по центру картинки.
Вы нашли решение?

Comment: хм, вроде в них, ну ладно если нет, появиться время , сяду вспомню что к чему и сделаю пример..

Comment: @MrFranke http://learn.javascript.ru/play/pa9l6   оно?

Comment: Не совсем :)
Основная проблема была в центрировании картинки именно по координатам курсора. Я ответил ниже что нашел решение и оставил ссылку на код. Там получилось немного дерганно, но алгоритм в целом верен.

Answer (score 0):

Вот готовый вариант кода с зумом канваса:
http://jsfiddle.net/qCzqF/1/